# How to get a function reference using reflection in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, reflection

Let's suppose I have an instance of a class X with a method Y of which we will know the name only at runtime, how can I get a reference to it using reflection?

Something like:

```
class X{

  fun Y(){
    
  }

}
```

I want to able to store the method Y in a variable and call it when needed.

I tried with `X::class.java::getMethod('Y').kotlinFunction` but then I will need to have an instance of such method to be able to call it, so it doesn't make any sense

Comment: You mean you want a reference to a function that is bound to a specific instance of X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, you need to find the function looping through class members, then call it with the required instance. if a function needs other arguments you need to pass it in order, but the first arg always needs to be the instance

```
class X {
    fun y() { println("I got called") }
}

fun main() {
    val x = X()
    x::class.members.find { it.name == "y" }
        ?.call(x)
}
```

**Performance:**

I ran the following code and got the following results:

```
    var start = System.nanoTime()
    val y = x::class.members.find { it.name == "y" }
    y?.call(x)
    var stop = System.nanoTime()
    println(stop - start)
    println()

    start = System.nanoTime()
    y?.call(x)
    stop = System.nanoTime()
    println(stop - start)
    println()


    start = System.nanoTime()
    x.y()
    stop = System.nanoTime()
    println(stop - start)
    println()



I got called
381566500 // with loop and reflection

I got called
28000 // reflection call

I got called
12100 // direct call
```

Comment: How slow is this way compared to a direct reference like X::Y?

Comment: If you don't want to deal with nullables and know your method exists, you could call `first` instead of `find`.

Comment: @Todd if you have other members `first` does not work

Comment: Not if you use the lambda version - `.first { it.name == "y" }`.

Comment: Btw, I just tested the code and I get a type mismatched exception. The method call() is expecting a X.Y instance, not an X instance

Comment: the code works fine @TitoTigi as you can see I even got the time needed for each

Comment: @Todd yeah thats better

Comment: `val function = eventListener::class.members.find{it.name == methodName}!!`
When I run `function.call(instance, functionParameter)` I get the following error: `Unexpected exception thrown: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch`
It expect an instance of type  `MyEventListener.onEvent(event.Event)` and not of `MyEventListener`

Comment: `MyEventListener.onEvent(event.Event)` is not a type, it's a function. don't expect to get clear errors from reflection. the error must be related to other parameters of the function. you should provide all parameters even the ones with a default value. if you don't want to pass default values use `callBy` method